# SSRS Custom Authentication - Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser

Tags: reporting-services

Hello i have a problem with SSRS Custom authentication. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/675943/ssrs-forms-authentication) but reporting server get this error:

> Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser

I am debugging code and I found out that error is in method ReportServerProxy.GetWebResponse:

```
 protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
      {
         WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
         string cookieName = response.Headers["RSAuthenticationHeader"];
         // If the response contains an auth header, store the cookie
         if (cookieName != null)
         {
            Utilities.CustomAuthCookieName = cookieName;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            Cookie authCookie = webResponse.Cookies[cookieName];
                // If the auth cookie is null, throw an exception
                if (authCookie == null) 
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                       "Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser");
                }
                // otherwise save it for this request
                AuthCookie = authCookie;
            // and send it to the client
            Utilities.RelayCookieToClient(authCookie);
         }
         return response;
      }
```

And i call this code in form:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
      {
            ReportServerProxy server = new ReportServerProxy();

            string reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
            string instanceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerInstance"]; //this constants are null

            // Get the server URL from the report server using WMI
            server.Url = AuthenticationUtilities.GetReportServerUrl("PC065", "MSSQLSERVER");

            server.LogonUser("user", "123", null); //throw exception

        }
```

Perhaps it is the first problem that my code does not see the configuration files, this is null:

```
string reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
            string instanceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerInstance"];
```

**This is my configuration**

ReportServer\web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Pages\Logon.aspx" name="sqlAuthCookie" timeout="60" path="/"></forms>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
          <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
      <identity impersonate="false" />
```

ReportServer\rsreportserver.config:

```
<Authentication>
        <AuthenticationTypes>
            <Custom />
        </AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
        <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
    </Authentication>

<UI>
        <CustomAuthenticationUI>
            <loginUrl>/Pages/UILogon.aspx</loginUrl>
            <UseSSL>True</UseSSL>
        </CustomAuthenticationUI>
        <ReportServerUrl>http://localhost/ReportServer</ReportServerUrl>
    </UI>
    <Security>
        <Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.Authorization, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity">
            <Configuration>
                <AdminConfiguration>
                    <UserName>username</UserName>
                </AdminConfiguration>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
    </Security>
    <Authentication>
        <Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.AuthenticationExtension, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity"/>
    </Authentication>
```

ReportManager\web.config:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ReportServer" value="PC065" />
    <add key="ReportServerInstance" value="MSSQLSERVER"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Please help me. I solve this problem for a very long time. My version of SQL Server is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-OD) (KB3144114) - 10.50.6542.0 (X64)   Feb 22 2016 18:07:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with authentication is in this code because authCookie is null:

```
protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
  {
     WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
     string cookieName = response.Headers["RSAuthenticationHeader"];
     // If the response contains an auth header, store the cookie
     if (cookieName != null)
     {
        Utilities.CustomAuthCookieName = cookieName;
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
        Cookie authCookie = webResponse.Cookies[cookieName];

        // If the auth cookie is null, throw an exception
        if (authCookie == null)
        {
           throw new Exception(
              "Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser");
        }
        // otherwise save it for this request
        AuthCookie = authCookie;
        // and send it to the client
        Utilities.RelayCookieToClient(authCookie);
     }
     return response;
  }
```

Comment: Why reporting server use cookie for authentication? Why I need cookie when i call LogonUser method? thanks